# Detectar URL WebView

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou com um probleminha, preciso saber a URL toda vez que a página é mudada.

o meu código funciona perfeitamente abre normalmente o youtube que seria o exemplo :

```
  WebView wv;

    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(wv.canGoBack()){
            wv.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
        //Enable Javascript
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        // set Render Priority to high
        wv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        // Load url
        wv.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/");
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }
```

Procurei soluções em sites gringos para o meu problema e descobri essa aqui

```
WebView wv;

public void onBackPressed(){
    if(wv.canGoBack()){
        wv.goBack();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
    //Enable Javascript
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    // set Render Priority to high
    wv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    // Load url
    wv.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/");
    wv.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
}

String currentUrl;

private class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url){
        Log.e("URL Now",url);
        currentUrl=url;
        view.loadUrl(url); // se eu usar isso, já não fica em branco a inicial, mas msm assim não alerta qndo muda de URL
        return true;
    }
}
```

Verifiquei os logs e vi que apareceu a URL assim que abriu o APP, porem não abriu o youtube, a tela fica toda branca.

Meu primeiro exemplo funciona perfeitamente, mas não atende minhas necessidades.

O meu objetivo é saber é detectar quando clico em um vídeo, para isso preciso saber.

Existe alguma outra forma mais elegante de fazer esse feito ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boa noite Bruno, creio que descobri + ou - o que você deseja, os dados que é pego você precisa filtrar com regex, vai depender muito do que você deseja, porque aparece todas as resource, mas de forma precisa, mudar a página, muda no log.

```
package com.example.offboard.youtubedownload;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView wv;

    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(wv.canGoBack()){
            wv.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
        //Enable Javascript
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        // set Render Priority to high
        wv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        // Load url
        wv.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/");
        wv.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
    }

     String currentUrl;

    private class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.e("Resource ",url); // talvez você precise usar regex para filtrar a URL, mas foi o único jeito que achei
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Vou abrir aqui o projeto e testar agora antes de ir pra academia.

Comment: Poxa cara funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado, mas pega tudo mesmo kkkk, eu me viro com as regex para filtrar a página, obrigado mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Essa pergunta já foi aceita mas vou colocar aqui algumas opções de métodos da `WebViewClient` que podem ser uteis.

> **[onPageStarted](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageStarted(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.Bitmap))** - É chamada para informar que uma pagina começou a carregar.
>
> ```
> void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon);
> ```

> **[onPageFinished](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String))** - É chamada para informar que uma pagina terminou de carregar.
>
> ```
> void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url);
> ```

> **[onLoadResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onLoadResource(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String))** - É chamada toda vez que um recurso vai começar a carregar.
>
> ```
> void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url);
> ```

> **shouldOverrideUrlLoading-([Deprecado](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)), [Novo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)))** - Chamada antes do carregamento de uma pagina, dá ao programador chance de controlar sé a pagina pode carregar.
>   Ao retornar `true` você aborta o carregamento, retornando `false` o carregamento e permitido.
>
> ```
> boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url);*
> boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request);
> ```
>
> <sub>*Esse método foi deprecado na API level 24</sub>

> **shouldInterceptRequest-([Deprecado](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)), [Novo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)))** - Intercepta o carregamento de um recurso, dando ao programador a chance de trocar o recurso, se retornar `null` o carregamento do recurso vai continuar normal.
>
> ```
> WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (WebView view, String url)*
> WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (WebView view, WebResourceRequest request);
> ```
>
> <sub>*Esse método foi deprecado na API level 21</sub>

---

Exemplo de implementação:

```
WebViewClient mWebViewClient = new WebViewClient(){

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon); /// executa o padrão
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url); /// executa o padrão
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url); /// executa o padrão
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request); /// executa o padrão
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request); /// executa o padrão
    }
};
```